# How to use Localstorage in textboxes that are populated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, textbox, local-storage

I am trying to save the content entered in the textbox using localstorage.

```
<input type='text' id='input1' name='discount_" +itemResultSet.getInt(5)+"' />
<input type='text' id='input2' name='note_" +itemResultSet.getInt(5)+"'/>
```

Here is my script:

```
   <script>
     document.getElementById('input1').onblur = function() {
    var in1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid1', in1);
         };
     document.getElementById('input2').onblur = function() {
    var in2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
        localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid2', in2);
        };
     document.getElementById('input1').value = localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid1');
     document.getElementById('input2').value = localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid2');
   </script>
```

EDIT:

These same textboxes appears more than once and my problem is that the content of the textbox is saved and retrieve only in the first two textboxes, it does not work on the next population of the same textboxes.

Comment: You're using `getElementsByClassName` but your inputs actually have  `id`s.

Comment: oops i have to edit that.

Comment: Did you assign individual IDs for each text box or is there more than one element with the ID `input1` on the page?

Comment: there is more than one element with the ID input1 on the page

Answer (score 0):

Although `localStorage` is an Object, it does provide an API, that I'd suggest using as it's more descriptive and easier to debug if you're setting/getting data incorrectly.

I wrote a very tiny <1kb script that abstracts `(local|session)Storage` behaviour to make it simple to set and get data:

https://github.com/toddmotto/vault/blob/master/dist/vault.js

It also provides some examples in the `README.md`.

Using Chrome Dev tools you can also look in the localStorage panel and ensure your data is being set correctly - that's all you need to see :)

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

To save localStorage contents you have to use `window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and to get it `window.localStorage.setItem(key)`

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hBTvA/1/

Comment: Yep, it worked. I have edited my question to clarify my problem better.